# How to check status of scheduled jobs

Tags: scheduled-job

We had to de-activate an old admin user.  The admin had some scheduled jobs like Mercury SMS. How can I check the status of these jobs and change their owner?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the status of job from

Setup > Monitor > Jobs > Apex Jobs

You cannot change the owner of the job, you have to delete the job and reschedule it. Delete the job from Setup > Monitor > Jobs > Scheduled Jobs
and reschedule it.

PS - Please accept the answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Arpit! What I did was to identify all scheduled jobs by visiting Setup>Monitor>Jobs> Apex Jobs (as you have also suggested) and then deleted the jobs. Then scheduled the jobs again by logging as the new system administrator.

The morale is we have to delete the jobs and schedule them again if the job owner has to be updated.

Why I had to do it was because when we deactivated the old admin Salesforce doesnt identify that scheduled jobs have to be rescheduled as well. So, the jobs kept failing as the owner was inactive :)